# How can I show that the elements of the unitary sphere are not parallel?

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, convex-analysis, normed-spaces, spheres

Let $(X,\|\cdot\|)$ be a normed vector space over the field $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{C}$ and let the unitary sphere defined as $S_X:=\{x\in X;\|x\|=1\}$. If $u, v\in S_X$, with $u\neq v$, then $u$ and $v$ are not parallel.
I just showed for $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$ but I need help for the case $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: How do you define "parallel"?

Comment: There is $k\in\mathbb{K}$ such that $u=kv$.

Answer (score 1):

It is  false in both cases. If $\|x\|=1$ then $x$ and $-x$ are parallel though $x \neq -x$.

Comment: In $\Bbb C$ it is, in some, sense, even "falser". You can take any $x$ and $e^{it}x$ for any real $t\not\equiv 0\pmod{2\pi}$.